# Define Raphael container by class name

Tags: jquery, class, raphael

Does anyone know if it's possible to set a Raphael container by a class name rather than an id?

For example, this works:

```
Raphael("holder", 100, 100));
```

And this works:

```
var container = document.getElementById('holder');
Raphael(container, 100, 100));
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var container = $('#holder');
Raphael(container, 100, 100));
```

And this doesn't work:

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('holder');
Raphael(container, 100, 100));
```

And this definitely doesn't work:

```
Raphael($('.holder:last'), 100, 100));
```

Raphael is playing nice with jQuery in every other part of my code except in this circumstance. I need to accomplish something like the last example. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //i've tried this one and it works with [0] to select first of array
    var container = $('#holder');
    Raphael(container[0], 100, 100));

    //so i think theses should work too
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('holder');
    Raphael(container[0], 100, 100));

    Raphael($('.holder:last')[0], 100, 100));
```